# How can I print a consecutive value from my database?

Tags: php, mysql

This is the table `data` in my mySQL database:

What I want to do is:

- If for an `id` exits `no` 01, 02 and 03, then print the consecutive value and `no` 01. If not then print the lowest missing `no` and the lowest `id` where the value is missing.

---

Example1:

```
    +-----------+
    | id  | no  | 
    +-----------+
    | 01  | 01  | 
    | 01  | 02  | 
    | 01  | 03  | 
    | 02  | 01  | 
    | 02  | 02  | 
    | 02  | 03  | 
    | 03  | 01  | 
    +-----------+
```

The result I wish:

id = 03, no=02

---

Example2:

```
    +-----------+
    | id  | no  | 
    +-----------+
    | 01  | 01  | 
    | 01  | 02  | 
    | 01  | 03  | 
    | 02  | 01  | 
    | 02  | 02  | 
    | 02  | 03  | 
    +-----------+
```

The result I wish:

id = 03, no=01

---

I am al little bit lost with my code:

```
$pdo = Database::connect();             
$sql = "SELECT  `id`, `no` FROM `data`";
$q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);  

foreach  ($result as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array("01", $value) AND in_array("02", $value) AND in_array("03", $value)) {
       echo "id=";
       echo "0";
       echo $key + 1;
       echo "<br>";
       echo "no=01";
       echo ",";
    } else {
       echo "id=".$key;
       echo ",";
       foreach  ($value as $row => $number) {
           echo "no=0";
           echo $number + 1;
           echo ",";
      }
    }
    echo "<br>";    
}
```

My result for example 1:

id=02,no=01

id=03,no=01

id=03,no=02

And for example 2:

id=02,no=01

id=03,no=01

Comment: Example 1 is straightforward. It starts with a CROSS JOIN. Example 2 is trickier as you're selecting data which does not exist at all within the database. Nevertheless, it's simple enough to fabricate in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a pure SQL solution without PHP conditional looping. Specifically, below uses a combination of a derived table, case/when logic, and union query:

```
# RETURN EXISTING RECORDS AS IS
SELECT data.`ID`, 
       data.`No`
FROM data

UNION

# NEXT CONSECUTIVE ROW
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN NextNo = 3 THEN NextID +1 ELSE NextID END As PHPID,
      CASE WHEN NextNo = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NextNo + 1 END As PHPNo    
FROM

     (SELECT data.`ID` As NextID, 
             data.`No` As NextNo
      FROM data
      ORDER BY data.`ID` DESC, data.`No` DESC
      LIMIT 1) As dT
```

Example 1 OUTPUT

```
ID  No
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
3   2
```

Example 2 OUTPUT

```
ID  No
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
3   1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, but for example 1 I need the output: `id = 03, no=02` and for example 2 I need the output `id = 03, no=01`

Comment: Just one record? Then, simply remove the top `SELECT` statement of the union query (including `UNION`)